# Floyd Steinberg dithering in GraphicsMagic or ImageMagic

Tags: image, graphicsmagick, dithering

I'm having trouble converting images to 1bit dithered images using GraphicsMagic. The converted images are to be used as input for a thermal printer.

I'm using the following command:

```
gm convert input.jpg -resize 384 -monochrome -dither out.bmp
```

The result is a 1bit dithered image, but the quality is different then e.g. a dithered image from GIMP, The GIMP (or resulting images from other programs) image looks slightly better.

Does anyone have tips to achieve the same results? (I have experimented with other GraphicsMagic options, but to no avail)

Original

[image: ORIGINAL]

GraphicsMagick

[image: GM]

GIMP

[image: GIMP]

Comment: Can you show an example of the difference in "quality"?  Quality can mean a lot of different things in this context.

Comment: Added some sample images ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can dither in a fashion closer to GIMP using this command:

```
convert scooter.png -resize 384 -dither FloydSteinberg -remap pattern:gray50 scooter_d.gif
```

[image]

By the way, you can get rather good results using an ordered dither like this:

```
convert scooter.png -colorspace gray -ordered-dither o8x8 result.gif
```

[image]

Kudos to Anthony Thyssen who wrote the excellent ImageMagick Usage pages - [Quantisation with ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/).

Comment: Nice! That looks more like it, I used GraphicsMagick, and it does not support the remap option (or i could not find it). So I switched to Imagemagick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the two different methods; these are nice